# Google Sheets Sumif formula error when criterion is date range

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to sum data from the Jones tab if its between the dates in C1 & B10. But it returns an formula parse error. I assume I am using some syntax incorrectly, any suggestions?

=sumifs(Jones!D20:25,Jones!B20:B25,"<="C1,Jones!B20:B25,">="B10)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tjRIAjh9jUkfNraRKOPqi4_rjH4ulVxWf0JzwotJy1M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: I also tried this:
=sumifs(Jones!D$2:D$211,Jones!B$2:B$211,"=<$C$1",Jones!B$2:B$211,"=>$B$10")

which returned 0 instead of 8

Comment: Please do [share a sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: I just had a look at your sheet. Cells in the formula you ask for (`=sumifs(Jones!D20:25,Jones!B20:B25,"<="C1,Jones!B20:B25,">="B10)`) are just empty. Could you please check the cells you are interested in and update your formula with the correct ones? And do let us know after by answering to this comment. It is the only way to know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
=sumifs(Jones!D20:D25,Jones!B20:B25,"=<C1",Jones!B20:B25,">=B10")
```

*(too much caffeine, not enough sleep)*

Comment: That gave the same parse error.

Comment: Answer updated.